# Debug.log file is never created?

Tags: debug, wp-debug

It's the first I have seen this.
In a project I'm working on, I tried to switch on the debug mode for wordpress to see logs. Even if I activate the debug_log in `wp-config.php`, `debug.log` file is never created in `/htdocs/wp-content/`

**wp-config.php**

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

@ini_set('display_errors',0);

define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

**wp-content dir rights**

[image]

**load.php**

```
if ( WP_DEBUG_LOG ) {
    ini_set( 'log_errors', 1 );
    var_dump( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/debug.log' );
    // display correctly this => "/htdocs/wp-content/debug.log";
    ini_set( 'error_log', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/debug.log' );
}
```

Comment: The writability of that folder is server specific, and not just the chmod, but the ownership of the folder is important. Having said that it looks like you're on a VPS, why not just use the PHP error logs instead?

Comment: @Tom J Nowell I'm using the plugin debug log to see logs in wordpress admin. I'm trying to trace with error_log()   which files are really loaded in a broken project of one customer. This plugin needs this file. So... Sould I talk with my client to change wp-content rights on the server side ?

Comment: hmmm that sounds like a suboptimal approach, can you not run the site locally? Then you could run it and watch the php error logs in realtime, or use a debugger

Comment: I'm waiting for the database access to copy all data and work it on localhost.

Comment: It's a very old and suboptimal way to debug things, the codex is very old, and there are far better ways to do it, especially on a local environment where you can use a real debugger. Are PHP error logs not available? All `WP_DEBUG_LOG` does is change where the log files location is

Comment: So what is the best practice to do this ? Have you got a link ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74592/discussion-between-j-bizmai-and-tom-j-nowell).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the problem.
In the Apache server, inside the php.ini, the variable...

```
track_errors = Off
```

To get this information, you can do in a phpfile `phpinfo();`.
So, to write the debug log file, you need to set `track_errors` as `'On'`.

Comment: This only stores the last error in a php variable that you can further use to script with in some other fashion. This doesn't turn on logging.

Comment: I got the same problem as you described upstairs, and changing this did not help to fix my problem. More then that, on one site, that do create and write to debug.log, this constant value is OFF.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions worked for me.

So I ran phpinfo() and found that error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log on my machine and I was finally able to see the error. In my case, a script was exceeding 30 seconds allowed of execution time.

So use phpinfo() and find out where your logs are stored!