# No debug log for WP multisite is created

Tags: multisite, debug

Where is the debug.log file stored on multisites?

---

I have inserted into my wp-config:

```
define ('WP_DEBUG', true);
define ('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define ('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
```

and analogous to https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress, a debug.log file should normally been saved in wp-content.

Neither in wp-content nor - as it is a multisite (in sub-directories) - in wp-content/uploads/sites, is somewhere a debug.log file.

Where is this stored normally in a multisite?
Or better, as I cannot find any file, why it is not created?

I found this answer for example:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/301298/146832

since track_errors is OFF at my shared hosting, too.
But since I am not a coder: how exactly has this file to be and where and what to add in this file?

Thanks for your help in advance.

---

*WP 5.1.1 • RAM 66.5 / 256M • SQL 231 • PHPv 7.2.13*

Comment: Do you suspect something is wrong with your site and you're expecting to see errors and warnings in the debug log? Or is it possible that there just isn't any errors or warnings to log?

Comment: I expect that something is wrong with my site and I am searching for errors; beyond my (fresh) sites, on different domains, on different multisites are very slow in backend and frontend - even with nearly not yet plugins installed.

Comment: `debug.log` should appear in the `wp-content` folder on both single and multisite WP installs, if there are any errors or warnings. You could test this by adding some faulty PHP (via FTP) to a subsite theme's functions.php, load the subsite once and see if the log file appears. Remove the faulty PHP afterwards. Query Monitor and Debug Bar Slow Actions (both in WP plugin repository) might also help you find what is making your site(s) slow.